# Handling an object with several ModalViewControllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I present a `UINavigationController` as a ModalViewController. The `UINavigationViewController` handles a segue of (navigated) `UIViewController`s. With my first ModalViewController (MVC) I want to create a new instance of my `NSObject` which has several properties. This works.

Now in every VC I have a slider to change one of the several properties of my object. At the last VC I want to save the object.

I'm using CoreData (which already works when I work with **all** of the properties in **one** VC).

Is there an *easy* way to achieve this?

(I'm also using `NSNotificationCenter`.)

**EDIT:**

- In MVC1 I send a `NSNotification` to `DetailTableViewController` by pressing `Next` in my `UINavigationBar`. MVC1 pushes to MVC2.
- When DTVC receives the `NSNotification` it does `self insertNewObject:` (standard Apple CoreData method) This methods works, I see a new instance of the object in my `UITableView` after dismissing the MVControllers.
- MVC2 has an `UISlider` which value I want to store in my object. So I did `#import "Object.h", @property (nonatomic, weak) Object * detailItem, @sythesize detailItem` and stored a certain value using `detailItem.property = NSNumber initWithInt etc.`. I press `Next`. MVC2 pushes to MVC3.
- MVC3 has also `#imported ... and @property ...`. It does in `viewDidLoad:` `NSLog(@"%i", [detailItem.property intValue]);` and shows `0` instead of `myInteger`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Which changes are necessary to make this piece of code work?

In `ModalViewController`

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(Object *)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
}
```

In `MasterViewController`

```
- (void)insertNewObject
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newManagedObject setValue:@"New Object" forKey:@"name"];
[self.firstAssistantViewController setDetailItem:(Object *)newManagedObject];

// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the new object along as a property to the other modal view controllers. The managed object contains a reference to the managed object context so you can save at any point.

So, for each modal view controller:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) Object* newManagedObject;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize newManagedObject;
```

And before you present each view controller:

```
modalViewControllerX.newManagedObject = newManagedObject;
```

Configure your UI (set the slider values etc) on `viewWillAppear:` like so:

```
self.slider.value = self.newManagedObject.property;
```

And update the managed object using the reverse when the slider value changes:

```
self.newManagedObject.property = self.slider.value;
```

In the final view controller, if you wish to save there, you can do this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.newManagedObject.managedObjectContext save:&error];
// Your own error checking goes here
```

Comment: How does this work? Do you have a code snippet? Just do `@property (strong, retain) anyID * anyDetailItem;` and `@synthesize` it in every VC?

Comment: That's pretty much it, yes - though the property should be `(nonatomic, weak)` since the core data framework will ensure it isn't released.

Comment: And how can I be sure that it is the same instance of the object? Do I have to do `<NSFetchedResultsController>` in every VC or is it enough to do this in the first and last controller where the object is created / saved?

Comment: I don't follow you, I thought you were making a new managed object in one modal view controller and then opening further ones to modify it? There is no need for a fetch request, just pass the object directly.

Comment: Thanks so far `jrturton`. I edited my question to make it easier to you to get the point. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you actually passing the new object, or just declaring the property? E.g are you doing MVC2.detailItem = newItem anywhere?

Comment: No, I'm not. So this will be the problem. Could you maybe edit the answer and add a code snippet? It's easier to understand when I see some code. Thank you again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6337/discussion-between-darwin-and-jrturton)

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot (like always!). Have a nice day!

Comment: One last thing: If I push to a normal `UIViewController` it works. But I present a `UINavigationController` as the ModalViewController and in it's root view I want to access the property. Do you have any hint for me how I could get it working? Thanks!

Comment: Create the new view controller and set its managed object property before you create the navigation controller using the new view controller as the root controller. If it's any more complex than that you should really ask a new question!

Answer (score 0):

As an advice you can use `NSUserDefault` to store and retrieve the same data in different views, you can use `NSUserDefaults` from any view controller :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults synchronize]
```